# Find a specific page in an XSL FO file

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo

I have a rather large DocBook book that is converted into a XSL FO file. This FO file is generating a

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: readRaster not supported!`

error when I try to compile it into PDF. I can tell from the output that this is happening on a specific page, but I can't see any way to actually determine what content has been placed at that page. What I need is some way to determine what content actually makes up the page the throws the error, so I can work backwards and fix the original source.

Are there any FO tags that appear once per page that I can count, or some other way to get to a specific page?

Comment: Can you show us the complete error message? It seems related to image processing (see http://kickjava.com/src/javax/imageio/ImageReader.java.htm). Are there many images in the document? You could try to remove images one by one and rerun the FO processor (FOP?) until the error goes away.

Comment: As it turns out, it was an issue with images. I also realised that the error provided a line and character reference (like 102:712) that allowed me to identify the offending source material.

I removed the images from the Docbook and the PDF compiled fine. I don't actually know what was wrong with the images (they work fine in HTML).